# Moving JButton text over its icon by pixels

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I am creating a desktop application in Java with lots of customized UI.
It also has a breadcrumb.
I've extended JButton class to customize it for my Breadcrumb buttons.

This is the screenshot of expected breadcrumb.

http://puu.sh/4MtvZ.jpg

[image]

The background of this breadcrumb is an ImageIcon.
But now, I am not able to perfectly align the JButton text over this background icon.

This is the screenshot of actual breadcrumb.

http://puu.sh/4MtDc.png

[image]

I've used following code to align the text.

```
setHorizontalTextPosition(CENTER);
setVerticalTextPosition(CENTER);
```

So, is their a way that I can move this text in pixels to its right position?

And also, I want root breadcrumb button "Schemes" to overlap some part of its preceding breadcrumb button "2000 Avenues" as shown in expected breadcrumb screenshot!
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [Overlap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/) for one solution.

> So, is their a way that I can move this text in pixels to its right position?

I don't understand this question. Why are you setting the alignment to center if you want it aligned to the left.

Edit:

I see. You are just using an Icon for the button outline and are then painting the text on top of the Icon. I thought your were using a custom shaped button with text). You can just use the default vertical/horizontal text position settings.

To shift the text to the left you can use:

```
button.setIconTextGap(10 - button.getIcon().getIconWidth());
```

Comment: Thanks for the overlap layout. And, the left alignment is not the solution because it will result this output. http://puu.sh/4MzSe.png

But I want to set the text a bit left as in expected screenshot. The text "Schemes" has more than enough left margin.

Comment: Also, I found out another way of doing it by overriding paintComponent() of JButton and drawing its text with drawString() on any position you like. But I think your solution is much better. Here is the final screenshot of actual breadcrumb, http://puu.sh/4MDnL.png